# how to create search function in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to create simple search function. I follow some example. but I was unable to get results. please help me.

//view page

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" action=" {{ base_url }}search/search_keyword" method = "post">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name = "keyword"size="15px; ">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default " type="submit" value = "Search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

//controller

```
function search_keyword()
{
    $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['results']    =   $this->mymodel->search($keyword);
    $this->twig->display('result_view.php',$this->data);
    //$this->load->view('result_view.php',$data);
}
```

}

//model

```
function search($keyword)
{
    $this->db->like('item_name',$keyword);
    $query  =   $this->db->get('bracelets');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 $this->twig->display('result_view.php',$this->data);
```

TO

```
 $this->load->view('result_view.php',$data);
```

Comment: <tr>
        <td><?php echo $val-> item_name?></td> 
</tr>
I use this code to show values. but it dose not give any value

Comment: not yet sir. I change my controller as you said.but I was unable to compete my result_view page.please help me

Comment: What error you get ?? Have you load twig library and haye you able to fetch data from database??

Comment: yes sir I load twig library correctly. I dose not get any php errors or data base errors. When I search an item my page dose not show me the result. it only shows this code part 
item_name?>

Comment: have your database return you result??

Comment: no sir. I use print_r function to check it.but it also dose not work properly

Comment: have you get the value in this `$keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');`??

Comment: yes sir. i get that value.when i search for a keyword like "mens" it grab my keyword correctly.

Comment: i found the problem sir. in my controller i put this code "print_r($data);" then it gives my an array according to  my search. now the problem is i cant pass that data value to my resent_view page.please help mt to slove this probloem

Comment: whay is your view name??

Comment: when i put "print_r($data);" in my relult_view.php page it also dose not working.So I think my view page did not get any data from controller

Comment: query is correct sir. because I get results when i put  "print_r($data);" in my controller.

Comment: check this [link](http://arpieb.com/2014/11/03/codeigniter-twig-quick-n-dirty-tm/)

Comment: finally i found a way to get results. I change "$this->twig->display('result_view.php',$data);" to "$this->load->view('result_view.php',$data);". then i got my results perfectly. I think problem was in twig. thank you very much Mr.Saty for helping me.you are a grate teacher sir...

Comment: How to load the search results on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

**Use This Function**

```
function search_keyword()
{
    $keyword=$this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['results']=$this->mymodel->search($keyword);
    $this->twig->display('result_view.php',$data);
}
```